# Discussing chances of pay review

Tags: professionalism, salary, ethics

I'm 2 weeks away from finishing my probation period.

Recently, things changed for me as my aunt died which leaves me and my wife as their guardian plus my boy started school and another is on its way. The circumstances of my aunt passing away has put an extra burden on me, leaving me financially very very tight which affects my immediate family.

I been very active in my work, mentoring new hires and getting them through the onboarding and my manager has praised me, while he knows how busy I had been with family and funeral but he applauded my on time work.

Should I ask him for a review/raise, as my contract says “after a year” but my circumstance ask for it?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong in asking.

Comment: `me and my wife as their guardian`.. whose guardian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Do not bring up financial hardships as a reason why you deserve a raise. Talk about your performance instead. However, if you agreed on a set wage in the beginning, and a higher wage wasn't agreed upon after the probation period, on what legitimate grounds would you now ask for a raise before 1 yr? Bit the bullet, clip coupons - do what it takes to shoulder new responsibilities.You aren't alone - network with others in your position and get practical strategies to meet the challenges.

Comment: If you are taking on the care of cousins, check the internet for things like this: "Depending on the state, it may help if you become licensed foster parents. This makes a lot of difference when negotiating subsidies."

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem asking for a pay review, and your manager may guess what's behind it, but the way to frame it would be that your contribution to the company is greater than your current pay acknowledges.

You could do this by comparing rates across the industry in your local geographic area, or by discussing the things you do for the company that are above and beyond what could be expected based on your current pay.

Professional pay reviews will be about a difference in contribution and reward. It sounds cynical, but companies pay people according to what the company can get from them, not based on their current circumstances.

I'm sorry to hear about your aunt, and hope things get better soon.

Comment: There r places which wasn’t in JD but I like to give n share. But I want to find a way to put it better which doesn’t hurt my final probation review

Comment: *I want to find a way to put it better* - read through the potential duplicate question mentioned in the comments above, under your question. There's a lot of good advice there on how to "put it better."